# How do I determine syndicate and collusion indication with clustering and network analysis on a large unlabeled user transaction data?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, predictive-modeling, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

How do I determine syndicate and collusion indication with clustering and network analysis on a large unlabeled user transaction data?
So far, I've only been training with labeled data on fraud-related users to cluster whether or not another user is suspicious (similar behaviors to fraud-related users) using Random Forest. Or using network analysis (NetworkX on Python) for requested or reported users to see users related to these suspicious/fraudelent users.

How do I implement this on a larger scale (with hundreds of millions of merchants and users) with unlabeled data? Is this possible? Would that confound the betweenness centrality index?

I tried using K-means clustering and get the 3 clusters as its optimal, but I can't seem to classify which of them are the low, medium, or high risk.

Any reference or advice would be helpful. Thank you!